# How do I convert a numpy Array to a data type that tensorflow can classify?

Tags: python, numpy, casting, tensorflow, classification

I am writing a Python program to detect the state of a chess board and I am using a sliding window to detect the position of each piece. My main program detects the chessboard within an image and passes its cropped picture to the my_sliding_window method. This is supposed to use Tensorflow to detect a piece in the sliding window. From [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) tutorial I saw that pictures are read like this:

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile('picture.jpg', 'rb').read()
```

But I don't want to read it from file as I already have the picture in a numpy array. How do make my numpy array in such a way that it can be classified by Tensorflow?

Thank you.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys
import cv2

image_path = sys.argv[1]


img = cv2.imread('picture.jpg')
image_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)
print type(image_data)    # this returns <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

# This is what is used in the tutorial I mentioned above
image_data2 = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
print type(image_data2)    # this returns <type 'str'>


# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) to convert your numpy array into a TensorFlow tensor:

> This function converts Python objects of various types to Tensor objects. It accepts Tensor objects, numpy arrays, Python lists, and Python scalars.

### Update

Ok, so what you're trying to do is to feed the numpy array `image_data`, with dimensions `[123, 82]` to the placeholder `DecodeJpeg/contents:0`. However that placeholder was defined with `shape=()` meaning it only accepts 0D tensors as input (see [tensor shapes](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types#shape)), hence throwing you an error.

What the [*original code*](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4) does is to read an image as a dimensionless string with:

```python
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

which is then fed to the `DecodeJpeg/contents:0` placeholder in:

```python
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

The easiest way to proceed and try to run your images through the pretrained graph would be to use the same `tf.gfile.FastGFile()` call for loading the images.

Comment: Using that function on my numpy array I get this error:

    TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.

I'll include my code in the question.

Comment: That's because you cannot pass a Tensor object as feed argument to `sess.run()`. Try passing the numpy array directly .

Comment: That's what I tried in the first place but I get this error:
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (123, 82) for Tensor u'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()'

. I get it from this line:
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

Comment: So I should (and in fact it is what I did while trying to understand this) write those images to file and read them back using tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read() ? It works but it is not very efficient. There must be a way to use the numpy arrays directly.

Comment: In your code, according to the line `img = cv2.imread('picture.jpg')` it seems like you already have the image file. My suggestion is that you do `image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile('picture.jpg', 'rb').read()`, and then feed that to the placeholder. Also, there is indeed a way to use numpy arrays as input to your placeholder but that would require you to either create the graph again, or attempt to modify the pretrained one (I'm not sure whether that's possible though).

Comment: The problem is that I simplified the code I posted here to make it more understandable but basically I am receiving a numpy array from another function and I want to classify that numpy array using the existing graph. I guess I'll just stick to writing images to file and then read them back until someone comes up with a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using this one-liner:

```
image_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv_image)[1].tostring()
```